# О странности правил

Tags: синтаксис

Не очень понятна логика постановки двоеточий перед некоторыми словами:

> Проблемы истинного патриотизма касались многие поэты, такие
> как (:) Некрасов, Толстой, Лермонтов.
> Проблемы истинного
> патриотизма касались многие поэты, как например: Некрасов, Толстой,
> Лермонтов.

Почему к одному случаю применимо требование не ставить двоеточие ***( если слова «такие как» употребляются после обобщающего слова перед рядом однородных членов (после слов «такие как» двоеточие не требуется)***, а к другому нет ***(если слова «как например» выступают перед перечислением (между обобщающим словом и рядом однородных членов), то перед ними ставится запятая, а после них – двоеточие)?***

---

Позиция здесь одна и та же: после обобщающего слова стоит уточняющий/присоединительный оборот, который вводится местоимением с союзом/союзом с вводным словом.

Comment: А Толстой поэт - это кто?

Comment: @Буратино Алексей Константинович, например.

Comment: @МаркИз Ясно, у Толстых значит в роду много творческих личностей?

Comment: После союза знак препинания обычно не ставится, а после вводного ставится.

Answer (score 1):

У этих предложений разные **исходные конструкции:**

(1) *Проблемы истинного патриотизма касались **ТАКИЕ  поэты, КАК** Некрасов, Толстой, Лермонтов.*

(2) *Проблемы истинного патриотизма касались **многие ПОЭТЫ**: Некрасов, Толстой, Лермонтов.*

В основе первого варианта лежит сочетание "***такие...как",*** поэтому оборот обособляется.